# Swift SpriteKit: png image appears black while the game is being run. How do I fix this?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, png, swift2, photoshop

I am making a game using Xcode, Swift and SpriteKit. I made a png image in photoshop which involves transparency, and it appears plain black in the game. I have other png images which also involve transparency and they appear the way they are supposed to. I don't think this is a code problem, but just in case, here's the code which introduces the image into the game (it is inside the `didMoveToView` function):

```
    let warning = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yellow_warning")
    warning.setScale(0.1)
    warning.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    warning.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(self.scene!.frame)+296, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.scene!.frame))
    warningsNode.addChild(warning)
```

`warningsNode` is a simple `SKNode` and is a child of the scene.

Here's the image I'm using

[image: Here's the image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I used gradient to create this image

Comment: Can you upload the exact image  you use ?

Answer (score 5):

Your image is too big.  Downloading the file it tells me that it is 270x9000 pixels.  Depending on the hardware in the iPhone/iPad/Mac your GPU may not be able to handle all those pixels.  At least on iPhone/iPad, the max (that I'm aware of) size of an image is 4096x4096.  You can check the max by creating an OpenGL context, and reading a property that tells you the maximum texture size.

I would scale your image down so that it is not taller than 4096 (or whatever your hardware is telling you).  While it is nice to have oversized textures to future-proof, you might be going just a bit too far.  I recommend changing a copy of this image, so that you don't have to regenerate it later on when there is more powerful hardware.

EDIT:  You could even make it 270x10 and stretch it, as nobody will be able to tell that it is stretched because it all looks the same going down (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).